# Using a web worker to manage large level

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm working on a little platform game written in JavaScript using canvas. The levels are kindle large so I figured this might be a sensible approach.

The main program maintains a game map object that in turn contains a 16x16 grid of the immediate area the player is in. The whole game map has a 300x300 grid though.

Does it make sense for me to use a web worker object that has the whole 300x300 grid in memory and continually sends the main program updates of the small 16x16 area as the player moves about?

It seems like a reasonable approach to me, but there may be something I don't know or see.

Comment: Maybe there is something that I don't know but IMM web workers use the browser allocated memory just like the main page, it's just that they can use an new processing thread (since js is single threaded). Then, what would be the benefit of web workers here?

Comment: If only to modularize the project a step further -      But, although I honestly don't know if I'm right or not -  I do believe it would decrease the load on the main thread and thus allow it to run faster ----  I'm actually in the process of writing up something to experiment and see if there any kind benefit

Comment: web workers will be useful if you have to generate the levels (computation heavy). If it's just a matter of caching data, I don't think you'll win anything, I guess accessing the cache is faster than talking to the webworker